# Kinematics Physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A car travels between two cities , half of the time it travels with **v1**=ct and the other half with **v2**=ct . The angle between **v1** and **v2** is ϴ. What is the average velocity of the car?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

Ad the displacement vectors (use components, or perhaps the  cosine rule for the magniude) to  compute the total displacement vector.  Average velocity is the total displacement vector diveded by the elapsed time.